# Unable to execute function in a list inside of a class

Tags: python

I'm am trying to create a list of function in Python. Though my code can "see" the function and attempt to execute it, it runs in to an error saying it's missing a positional argument `self`.

```py
class cpu:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        self.instructions[0]()

    def add(self):
        print("instr add")

    def beq(self):
        print("instr beq")

    instructions = [add, beq]

cpu_ = cpu()
cpu_.execute()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\src\error.py", line 17, in <module>
    cpu_.execute()
  File "C:\...\src\error.py", line 6, in execute
    self.instructions[0]()
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the code giving the error: `cpu.py`, line 61, in `execute instruction()`

Comment: This is the cpu.py, main.py only calls the class, fill the memory with test binary and then cpu.execute()

Comment: You are using OOP. So you just can't call the function. You need to instantiate the class, then call the method

Comment: I did, I'll add main.py here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
    ...
    self.instructions[0](self)
    ...
```

This seems to do the trick. I am not too sure why though.

Comment: I did create one, in main.py.

Comment: Not too sure what's the probelme is then, but see my edited reply...

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this solves my problem? I did created an instance when I first encounter this problem. When I execute the commands directly, they all worked without error. The problem is when I put the functions in a list inside a class, they don't work.

Comment: You dont show your code (a simplified version at best that replicates the problem), it's all guess work and hard to tell, sorry.

Comment: I originally  thought the simplified version might be enough. I'll upload to github later. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[mikey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149194/10426037) is correct, but let's explain why.

As the traceback says, `add` needs an argument `self`. So whenever you call `add`, you need to pass at least an argument.

In python, this is done "under the carpet" by the interpreter in most typical situations. When you call a class methond inside a class, you do:

```
self.execute()
```

or when you call a method from a class instance:

```
cpu_.execute()
```

In the background, the interpreter uses `self` or the `cpu_` instance as a first argument of the `execute` method.
In other terms, `cpu_.execute()` is a syntactic sugar for `cpu.execute(cpu_)`, where you call a method from the class object and pass an instance of the class as first argument.

Now, when you do:

```
def execute(self):
    self.instructions[0]()
```

Here you are calling the method referred in `instruction[0]`, but since the method is defined in a list, you cannot use the syntactic sugar. There is no `self` before a dot. Sure, there is `self` before `instructions`, but that one refers to the `instructions` list, and not to the content of the list.
So you have to explicitly provide the `self` argument.

```
self.instructions[0](self)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I roughly know why:).